# Simplify the following $(1\cdot2)+(2\cdot3)+(3\cdot4)+\dots+(n\cdot(n+1))$

Tags: combinatorics

Simplify the following $(1\cdot2)+(2\cdot3)+(3\cdot4)+\dots+(n\cdot(n+1))$.

How do i do this by using these identities.

$C^r_r + C^{r+1}_r + C^{r+2}_r + ....+C^{n}_r = C^{n+1}_{r+1}$

Or

$C^r_0 + C^{r+1}_1 + C^{r+2}_2 + ....+C^{r+k}_k = C^{r+k+1}_{k}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$(1\times2)+(2\times3)+(3\times4)+\dots(n\times(n+1)) =\sum_{k=1}^nk(k+1) \\
\begin{align}
& =2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}2 \\
& =2\sum_{k=1}^nC_2^{k+1} \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2\binom{k}{2}=(k-1)k$. Hence
$$(1\cdot2)+(2\cdot3)+(3\cdot4)+\dots+(n\cdot(n+1))=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}2\binom{k}{2}=2\binom{n+2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\pars{1 \cdot 2} + \pars{2 \cdot 3} + \pars{3 \cdot 4} + \cdots + \bracks{n\pars{n + 1}}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\pars{k+1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bracks{k\pars{k - 1} + 2k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k^{\underline{2}} + 2k^{\underline{1}}}
\qquad\qquad
\pars{~a^{\underline{n}} \equiv a\pars{a - 1}\ldots\pars{a - n + 1}\
\mbox{is the}\ falling\!-\!factorial~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{1 \over 3}\,k^{\underline{3}} + k^{\underline{2}}
\,\right\vert_{\ 1}^{\  n + 1} =
{1 \over 3}\,\pars{n + 1}^{\underline{3}} + \pars{n + 1}^{\underline{2}} -
{1 \over 3}\,1^{\underline{3}} - 1^{\underline{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\pars{n + 1}n\pars{n - 1} + \pars{n + 1}n =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 3}\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}n} =
{1 \over 3}\,n^{3} + n^{2} + {2 \over 3}\,n
\end{align}

Comment: $k(k-1)+2k\ne k^2+2k^1$

Comment: @SimpleArt Note that the right hand side involve
[falling-factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
k^{\underline{2}} = k\left(k - 1\right)\,,\qquad k^{\underline{1}} = k
$$
such that
$k^{\underline{2}} + 2k^{\underline{1}} = k^{2} + k = k\left(k + 1\right)$. I just add some text in the answer to point out the falling factorial. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: @SimpleArt There is a nice discussion about similar behaviour of sums and integrals which involve $falling$- and $rising$-$factorials$ in the Knuth et.al. Concrete Mathematics book.

Comment: Shouldn't you use ':=' rather than $\equiv$?

Comment: @SimpleArt I used $\equiv$ to point out it's $a\ definition$. $=$ works fine too ( I guess so ). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer using your combinatorics argument, but I figured I would provide an arguably easier solution in case you just want an answer. 
What you have is basically the sum 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k(k+1)$$. 
You can break this up into two sums, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^2+\sum_{k=0}^n k$$
Now, we have well known solutions for these sums,  which are,  respectively, $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Adding those together will yield your answer.